# Node JS queries on Dynamo DB hangs forever using IAM roles

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to connect my Node JS app to Dynamo DB from a EKS instance using IAM roles.

As you probably know, credentials should be passed automatically to the container in this case. As a prove of that, I tried to install the `aws-cli` within the same container and it's perfectly working.

**However, my Node JS script is hanging forever when I try to execute it and no errors are returned.**

I checked few things: proxy, permissions (OS user), etc.. Nothing seemed related to this problem.

```
const { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");

const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: "eu-west-1",
});

// Set the parameters
const params = {
  KeyConditionExpression: "itemRef = :itemRef",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":itemRef": { S: "ABC" },
  },
  TableName: "my-sandbox",
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await ddbClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
    data.Items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      console.log(element);
      return data;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

run();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hanging suggests no network route to the DynamoDB service endpoint. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because the `aws-cli` is able to reach it.